# Apache - maximum number of threads?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've tried to configure my Apache server to use a maximum of 120 threads and one (Oracle) SQL connection per thread. I did this by setting:

```
MaxClients 120
```

in httpd.conf file. I also set:

```
oci8.max_persistent = 1
```

in php.ini file.

However, I see the number of threads/connections occasionally going over 120. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: How high over 120?

Answer (score 6):

As bindbn tells you, you should check the MPM

```
# apache2 -V | grep "Server MPM" 
Server MPM:     XXXX
```

And as you answer him, you're using 'prefork', configuration it's pretty similar to worker:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  StartServers            8
  MinSpareServers         5
  MaxSpareServers        20
  MaxClients            150
  MaxRequestsPerChild  1000
</IfModule>
```

More info:

http://www.devside.net/articles/apache-performance-tuning

http://www.camelrichard.org/apache-prefork-vs-worker

Comment: Both links are broken.

Answer (score 4):

Check MPM:

```
# apache2 -V | grep "Server MPM"
Server MPM:     Worker
```

Check that the correct section changed:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      60
    ThreadLimit          55
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          120
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Server MPM is actually set to "prefork", so that no threading is used. The MaxClients directive is set on the global level.